# Disable or enable button per item in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of participants. Each participant have dial and mute buttons. I want to disable mute button at first and enable it only after dial button is clicked. Currently, if I click on dial button of say Participant 1, all the mute buttons of other participants enables. But I want to enable mute button of only Participant 1.

HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <table>
    <tr ng-model="participant.partName" ng-repeat="participant in participants">
      <td>{{participant.partName}}</td>
      <td>
       <button ng-click="mutePart(participant.partName);">Mute</button>
      </td>

      <td>
       <button ng-click="dial(participant.partName)">Dial</button>
      </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
```

JS:

```
 $scope.participants = [
{
  partName: 'abc',
  partId: '123'
},
{
  partName: 'def',
  partId: '1234'
},
{
  partName: 'xyz',
  partId: '12345'
},
]
   $scope.mutePart = function(item){

  }
 $scope.dial = function(item){

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <table>
    <tr ng-model="participant.partName" ng-repeat="participant in participants">
      <td>{{participant.partName}}</td>
      <td>
       <button ng-disabled="!callSessions[$index]" ng-click="mutePart(participant.partName);">Mute</button>
      </td>

      <td>
       <button ng-click="dial(participant.partName, $index)">Dial</button>
      </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
```

controller:

```
$scope.callSessions= {};
$scope.dial = function(name, index){
    $scope.callSessions[index] = true;
}
```

Comment: I get a console error 'callSessions is not defined' in this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/QIXb271P40Rv1dIQZPbG). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `$scope.callSessions[index] = true;` Typo from my part, sorry.

Comment: Cool. Took an accepted answer literally and overlooked that typo.

Answer (score 0):

Since `ngRepeat` will create its own child scope per each iterated item, you can set a variable in the view that will be limited to that scope:

```
<tr ng-repeat="participant in participants">
  <td>{{participant.partName}}</td>
  <td>
   <button ng-disabled="!isDialing" ng-click="mutePart(participant.partName);">Mute</button>
  </td>

  <td>
   <button ng-click="isDialing = true; dial(participant.partName)">Dial</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Also, the `ngModel` on the `tr` is useless. Remove it. If you need more control over the variable (like to re-enable it when it's done calling, you should add a property to your model and toggle it):

```
{
    partName: 'abc',
    partId: '123',
    isDialing: false //Added property, now toggle this
}
```